# Every Jordan function $\phi$ on $A$ is multiplicative.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I am reading the following proposition by :

*FF. Bonsall and J. Duncan, Complete Normed Algebras, pg. 79*

> **Definition:** A Jordan function on $A$ is a nonzero linear functional $\phi$ on $A$ such that $\phi(a^2)=\phi(a)^2$ for every $a \in A$.
>
> **Proposition:**
> Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. Every Jordan function $\phi$ on $A$ is multiplicative.

**Proof:**

Consideration the identity $$\phi((a+b)^2)=\phi(a+b)^2$$ gives $$\phi(ab + ba)=2\phi(a)\phi(b)~~~ (a,b \in A)$$
and so the result is trivial is $A$ is commutative.

I understand this part completely. It is the following part that I can not seem to see why:

> If $\phi$ is not multiplicative then there exists $a,b \in A$ such that $\phi(a)=0, \phi(ab)=1$. Then $\phi(ba)=-1$. Let $c=bab$. Then $$0=2\phi(a)\phi(c)=\phi(ac+ca)=\phi((ab)^2)+\phi((ba)^2)=2$$

Why does there exist an $a,b \in A$ such that those conditions hold? Can anyone please help give me some clarity as to why that is true?

Comment: http://www.iith.ac.in/~suku/SukuThesis.pdf page 23 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to check that if $A$ is non-unital, a Jordan function $\phi$ extends to a Jordan function of the unitization $\tilde A$.

So, we may assume without loss of generality that $A$ is unital.

If $\phi$ is not multiplicative, there exist $x,y\in A$ with $\phi(xy)\ne\phi(x)\phi(y)$. We may write this as $\phi(xy-\phi(x)y)\ne0$. Thus, multiplying either $x$ or $y$ by an appropriate constant, we may assume 
$$
\phi(xy-\phi(x)y)=1.
$$
Now we may write this as $\phi((x-\phi(x)1)y)=1$. So, if $a=x-\phi(x)1$, $b=y$, we get
$$
\phi(a)=0,\ \ \phi(ab)=1. 
$$